# How to remove a Linear Layouts child from the 2nd position?

Tags: java, android

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.view.View.unFocus(android.view.View)' on a null object
>   reference.

**I want to remove *all the views* from a Linear Layout, *except the first two views*.**
The views that i want to delete were dynamically created.
This is what i've tried:

---

//Edit, i've called it with a wrong layout, but still not working

```
LinearLayout myFirstLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linLay);
deleteLinearLayoutChild(myFirstLinearLayout);
```

---

**This is the function:**

```
private void deleteLinearLayoutChild(LinearLayout linearView){
        int childNumber = linearView.getChildCount();
        Log.d("childNumb", childNumber+"");
        if (childNumber > 2){
            for (int i=2;i<childNumber;i++){
                linearView.removeViewAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code will not work. You increase counter, but at the time children count decrease. You should use while loop instead while (linearView.getChildCount > 2) removeView(2). But I recommend use separate layout for dynamic views and just use removeAllViews

Comment: I must use one layout for the dynamically added views. Just wrote the code you, said, and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should delete the views from layout in reverse order. Check below:

```
for (int i = childNumber - 1; i > 1; i--){
    linearView.removeViewAt(i);
}
```

***If you use while-loop, then you have to call `getChildCount` in every iteration***

Answer (score 1):

You are passing wrong layout might be :

```
LinearLayout myFirstLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linLay);
deleteLinearLayoutChild(myFirstScrollView); //
deleteLinearLayoutChild(myFirstLinearLayout) // pass myFirstLinearLayout
```

Also these are the method you can use ;

```
myFirstLinearLayout .removeView(view)//remove particular view
myFirstLinearLayout.removeViewAt(position);//remove view from particular position
```

Comment: As i've copied here  the code, i've edited it, so it's wrong here, i will edit it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use recycler view or list view to add and remove view in a view group, it will be better practice for you. Several issue may occur in future if you use your methodology , like :
1. Configure change issue
2. Memory leak issue
3. already have child during adding view issue
4. UI lagging issue(ANR may occur)

Comment: Ok, i will take a look at it. Thanks